# How do I setup a public static IP in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: networking, ubuntu-9.10, isp, static-ip

I have an Ubuntu 9.10 server and I need to setup a static public IP.

Our office already had a network setup by Cisco, so the router is configured to forward the requests to the server.

Here is the information from the ISP:

> Static IP’s:
>
> x.y.z.59
>
> x.y.z.60
>
> x.y.z.61
>
> x.y.z.62
>
> Gateway:
>
> x.y.z.33
>
> Netmask:
>
> 255.255.255.224
>
> Primary Name Server:
>
> a.b.c.245
>
> Secondary Name Server:
>
> a.b.c.30

I just need to know the commands to run in Ubuntu (non graphical) to setup this server with the static IP of: **x.y.z.61**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to have the following contents:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
address 127.0.0.1
netmask 255.0.0.0

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address x.y.z.61
    netmask 255.255.255.224
    gateway x.y.z.33
```

Though you may need to use something other than `eth0` depending on your system. Running `ifconfig` will give you a list of network interfaces. Then you would edit `/etc/resolv.conf` for you DNS entries:

```
nameserver a.b.c.245
nameserver a.b.c.30
```

And finally issue the command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Answer (score 2):

Network configuration is documented at https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/serverguide/C/network-configuration.html

Comment: I guess I am looking for mar specific help, regarding the specific IPs/gateway/netmask. It would be nice to actually see the commands for a public IP configuration, with the proper netmask. Do I use the Netmask in my question? Or do I use something different?